# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot

Tags: boot, lenovo, bios

I followed a tutorial to activate my wifi connection on my Lenovo Legion Y520 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.

At some points, I had to load default values from BIOS, and since then Ubuntu doesn't boot properly.

The error messages I get are:

[image]

I still have some important files on this computer, so I cannot format everything and do a clean install.

Comment: Try to re-enable UEFI in the BIOS, it seems there is a problem with UEFI.

Comment: Boot Mode is already set as UEFI in the BIOS.

Comment: Ok, so let's go to the bios and verfiy that all your drives are enable/detected. It's also possible it's a problem with sata controller mode (legacy vs ahci)...

Comment: Wow. Ok Thank you so much I just changed sata controller from legacy to ahci and everything is working well now!

Comment: Since it worked, I put the comments into an answer! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the BIOS, and verify the UEFI settings (legacy, ,UEFI secure boot, ...),.

Then have a look at your drives, they should be enabled and detected by the BIOS.

And last make sure the SATA controller is in the AHCI mode (i.e not in the legacy or RAID or something).